# Copy value from one Series / DataFrame to Another only when is finite and nonzero and preserve existing value when not finite and zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Series which has values and zeros, which holds current readings (`newv`), at a given point in time. The zero indicates there is no new reading for a given set of readings. I want to maintain another Series with the last known value (`vals`).

For this you should be able to copy nonzero values from the the series holding the current values to the one with the last known values and also preserve the values in the last known values when the reading of the current value is zero (the resulting `vals`).

How can I maintain these data structures as Series and Data Frames?

---

E.g.

Given `vals = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])` and `newv = pd.Series([0, 22, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])` I want to arrive at `vals = pd.Series([1, 22, 3, 44, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`

Given `vals = pd.Series([1, 22, 3, 44, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])` and `newv = pd.Series([11, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])` in the next iteration, I want to arrive at `vals = pd.Series([11, 22, 33, 44, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, with updated examples I think you just need to assign new values to `vals` whereever `newv` is greater than zero. Do it like this:

```
vals = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
newv = pd.Series([0, 22, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
vals.loc[newv>0] = newv
```

If you have a DataFrame with a few new iteration columns you could make a column with last known values like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['vals'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
df['new1'] = [0, 22, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
df['new2'] = [11, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
df['last_known'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x>0].iloc[-1], axis=1)
```

Or you can apply the previous answer's method over `df`'s columns and get current values at every iteration:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.replace, axis=1, to_replace=0, method='ffill')
```

Which will produce

```
   vals  new1  new2
0     1     1    11
1     2    22    22
2     3     3    33
3     4    44    44
4     5     5     5
5     6     6     6
6     7     7     7
7     8     8     8
8     9     9     9
```

---

#### original answer below

You can do this by replacing zero values in a Series with `NaN`s and then using `fillna` method to forward-fill missing values. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,0,0,0,4,0,5])
s2 = s1.replace({0:np.NaN}).fillna(method='ffill')
```

This is the result in `s2`:

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
5    3.0
6    4.0
7    4.0
8    5.0
```

As @ayhan suggests in the comments an even better way is to use `replace` with a method parameter:

```
s2 = s1.replace(0, method='ffill')
```

Comment: replace also has a method parameter that you can use directly: `s1.replace(0, method='ffill')`

Comment: Thanks, @ayhan, I didn't know this and it's awesome =). I added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. This was not exactly what I was looking for. I added an example.

Comment: @Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena, please see the updated answer.